# terraform i shown in CMD but it says "command not found" in git bash

Tags: terraform, git-bash

I installed terraform on windows 10. When I try to check (and actually use it) in CMD terminal is fine but in GitBash it says command not found. Any idea what should be the problem.

[image]

Comment: Try `./terraform`.

Answer (score 0):

fixed by it self when I checked terraform version in powerShell as administrator. It was shown correctly and after that it was Ok in CMD and in GitHub

Answer (score -1):

USER@DESKTOP-3MQ9MTA MINGW64 /g/terraform12
$ dir
terraform.exe

USER@DESKTOP-3MQ9MTA MINGW64 /g/terraform12
$ terraform --version
bash: terraform: command not found

USER@DESKTOP-3MQ9MTA MINGW64 /g/terraform12
$ ./terraform --version
Terraform v0.12.24

USER@DESKTOP-3MQ9MTA MINGW64 /g/terraform12